# Textblock/Textbox in XAML and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I am a complete "weekend warrior" to programming so go gentle on me, please...

I want to achieve a simple task, which I had no problem with in plain C# (TextBox.Text = "Something";)

I have a textbox and a textblock in XAML, and I want to populate them from C#, simple as that - run the web app and pull the predefined strings from the C# code. I have been searching for 2 days now and can't find a straight answer. I don't want any triggers (buttons), just filling e.g. textbox on load with a C# string. A simple code example on both XAML and C# side would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Sasa

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question...

```
<!--xaml-->
<TextBox x:Name="txtMyTextBox"/>

// C#
// Window constructor
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtMyTextBox.Text = "Something";
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, I don't know why I didn't get it to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve what you try to achieve (if I understood correctly), is to add the UI elements to your window and set a `Name` for each of them. This way, you can access them in your code-behind as seen below.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="37,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="103" Width="239"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

While there are certainly more "refined" ways to achieve the same, once you named your UI elements in xaml, you can access them just as other object instances in your code-behind.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "Hello TextBox1!";
            TextBlock1.Text = "Hello TextBlock1!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little more help - how do I do it in this context, what is the correct syntax (I don't know how to properly format the code here):                                                                                                                                                                                                                 namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}